# spark random forest classifier - get labels as String

Tags: java, apache-spark, random-forest, libsvm

I'm new with Spark and I want to use it for random forest classifier.
I use Iris data in libsvm format to build a model.

My question is - how can I get labels as string? (In this case - the labels are types of Iris flowers).

When data is converted to libsvm format each label gets an integer that represent it, but I don't know how to go back to string label.

Is it possible with libsvm? Or should I use another format?

Here is my code:

```
public PipelineModel runRandomForestAlgorithm(String dataPath) {

System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:/hadoop");
SparkSession spark =
    SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaRandomForestClassifierExample").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();

/* Load and parse the data file, converting it to a DataFrame. */
DataFrameReader dataFrameReader = spark.read().format("libsvm");
Dataset<Row> data = dataFrameReader.load(dataPath);

/* Index labels, adding metadata to the label column.
   Fit on whole dataset to include all labels in index. */
StringIndexerModel labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("label").setOutputCol("indexedLabel").fit(data);

/* Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
   Set maxCategories so features with > 4 distinct values are treated as continuous. */
VectorIndexerModel featureIndexer =
    new VectorIndexer().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("indexedFeatures").setMaxCategories(4).fit(data);

/* Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing) */
Dataset<Row>[] splits = data.randomSplit(new double[]{0.9, 0.1});
Dataset<Row> trainingData = splits[0];
testData = splits[1];

/* Train a RandomForest model. */
RandomForestClassifier rf =
    new RandomForestClassifier().setLabelCol("indexedLabel").setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures").setNumTrees(10);

/* Convert indexed labels back to original labels. */
IndexToString labelConverter =
    new IndexToString().setInputCol("prediction").setOutputCol("predictedLabel").setLabels(labelIndexer.labels());

/* Chain indexers and forest in a Pipeline */
Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(new PipelineStage[]{labelIndexer, featureIndexer, rf, labelConverter});

/* Train model. This also runs the indexers. */
PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(trainingData);

/* Make predictions. */
Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(testData);

/* Select example rows to display. */
List<Row> predictionAsRows =
    predictions.select("predictedLabel", "label", "features", "rawPrediction", "probability").collectAsList();

predictionAsRows.forEach(row -> {
  System.out.println("predictedLabel: " + row.get(0) + " , " + "label: " + row.get(1) + " , " + "features: " + row.get(2) + " , " +
      "predictions: " + row.get(3) + " , " + "probabilities: " + row.get(4));
});
```

And here is the output:

```
    predictedLabel: 1.0 , label: 1.0 , features: (4,[0,1,2,3],
    [-0.833333,0.333333,-1.0,-0.916667]) , predictions: [10.0,0.0,0.0] , 
    probabilities: [1.0,0.0,0.0]
    predictedLabel: 1.0 , label: 1.0 , features: (4,[0,1,2,3],                                
    [-0.555556,0.166667,-0.830508,-0.916667]) , predictions: [10.0,0.0,0.0] 
    , probabilities: [1.0,0.0,0.0]
    predictedLabel: 2.0 , label: 2.0 , features: (4,[0,1,2,3],
    [-0.333333,-0.75,0.0169491,-4.03573E-8]) , predictions: [0.0,0.0,10.0] , 
    probabilities: [0.0,0.0,1.0]
    predictedLabel: 2.0 , label: 2.0 , features: (4,[0,1,2,3],
    [-0.166667,-0.416667,-0.0169491,-0.0833333]) , predictions: 
    [0.0,0.0,10.0] , probabilities: [0.0,0.0,1.0]
    predictedLabel: 2.0 , label: 2.0 , features: (4,[0,1,2,3],
    [0.166667,-0.25,0.118644,-4.03573E-8]) , predictions: [0.0,0.0,10.0] , 
    probabilities: [0.0,0.0,1.0]
    predictedLabel: 2.0 , label: 2.0 , features: (4,[0,1,2,3],
    [0.277778,-0.166667,0.152542,0.0833333]) , predictions: [0.0,0.0,10.0] , 
    probabilities: [0.0,0.0,1.0]
    predictedLabel: 2.0 , label: 2.0 , features: (4,[0,2,3],
    [0.5,0.254237,0.0833333]) , predictions: [0.0,0.0,10.0] , probabilities: 
    [0.0,0.0,1.0]
    predictedLabel: 3.0 , label: 3.0 , features: (4,[0,1,2,3],
    [-0.166667,-0.416667,0.38983,0.5]) , predictions: [0.0,9.875,0.125] ,         
    probabilities: [0.0,0.9875,0.0125]
    predictedLabel: 3.0 , label: 3.0 , features: (4,[0,1,2,3],
    [0.555555,-0.166667,0.661017,0.666667]) , predictions: [0.0,10.0,0.0] , 
    probabilities: [0.0,1.0,0.0]
    predictedLabel: 3.0 , label: 3.0 , features: (4,[0,1,2,3],
    [0.833333,-0.166667,0.898305,0.666667]) , predictions: [0.0,10.0,0.0] , 
    probabilities: [0.0,1.0,0.0]
    predictedLabel: 3.0 , label: 3.0 , features: (4,[0,2,3],
    [0.222222,0.38983,0.583333]) , predictions: [0.0,10.0,0.0] , 
    probabilities: [0.0,1.0,0.0]
    predictedLabel: 3.0 , label: 3.0 , features: (4,[0,2,3],
    [0.388889,0.661017,0.833333]) , predictions: [0.0,10.0,0.0] , probabilities: [0.0,1.0,0.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using libsvm format you can only get an integer for each class, so you can't get a string class label from there.

You could utilize the `IndexToString()` converter by using the `setLabels()` method. Simply input the array of labels you have. For this to work, you should probably remove the `StringIndexerModel()` (it's unnecessary anyways as the classes are numbers, not strings). Example:

```
String[] labels = {"Setosa", "Versicolor", "Virginica"}; 
IndexToString labelConverter = new IndexToString().setInputCol("prediction").setOutputCol("pred‌​ictedLabel").setLabe‌​ls(labels);
```

Optionally, you can create a separate `Map` where you map the integers to the string labels. For the Iris dataset it could look like this:

```
Map labels = new HashMap();
labels.put(1, "Setosa");
labels.put(2, "Versicolour");
labels.put(3, "Virginica");
```

Then you can use this `Map` to get the string labels after all Spark transformations are done.

Hope it helps.